# Why my terminal gives me this error when i try to comlile using make?

Tags: c

When i try to do the make , it gives me this error.

mgarrt:~/Documents 110% make
cc -o threadcircuit threadcircuit.c
/tmp/ccLMBfl6.o: In function `main': threadcircuit.c:(.text+0x340): undefined reference to` pthread_create'
threadcircuit.c:(.text+0x3d2): undefined reference to `pthread_join'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:2: threadcircuit] Error 1

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
// count is shared between threads
int count = 0;
// minimum and maximum values for check_circuit function
// for passing to each thread
typedef struct min_max_data{
int min;
int max;
}min_max_data;
/* Return 1 if 'i'th bit of 'n' is 1; 0 otherwise */
#define EXTRACT_BIT(n,i) ((n&(1<<i))?1:0)
int check_circuit(int z)
{
int v[16];        /* Each element is a bit of z */
int i;
for(i = 0; i < 16; i++) v[i] = EXTRACT_BIT(z,i);
if((v[0] || v[1]) && (!v[1] || !v[3]) && (v[2] || v[3])
      && (!v[3] || !v[4]) && (v[4] || !v[5])
      && (v[5] || !v[6]) && (v[5] || v[6])
      && (v[6] || !v[15]) && (v[7] || !v[8])
      && (!v[7] || !v[13]) && (v[8] || v[9])
      && (v[8] || !v[9]) && (!v[9] || !v[10])
      && (v[9] || v[11]) && (v[10] || v[11])
      && (v[12] || v[13]) && (v[13] || !v[14])
      && (v[14] || v[15])) {
    printf ("%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d\n",
      v[0],v[1],v[2],v[3],v[4],v[5],v[6],v[7],v[8],v[9],
      v[10],v[11],v[12],v[13],v[14],v[15]);
    return 1;
}
return 0;
}
// thread function
void* check_circuit_thread_function(void* arg)
{
min_max_data *mmdata;
int i;
// convert arg to structure
mmdata = (min_max_data*)arg;
for (i = mmdata->min; i <= mmdata->max; i++)
    count += check_circuit(i);
}
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
int i, thread_count;
struct timeval t1, t2;
pthread_t threads[32];
void *thread_result;
int res;
int each_thread_Z = 0;
min_max_data mmdata;
int start, end = 0;
// check arguments
if(argc < 2){
    printf("Thread count expected\n");
    return 1;
}
gettimeofday(&t1, 0);
// get thread count
thread_count = atoi(argv[1]);
// get each thread maximum circuit check integer
each_thread_Z = 65536/thread_count;
start = 0;
end = each_thread_Z;
// create threads
for(int i = 0; i < thread_count; i++){
    // set min and max data
    mmdata.min = start;
    mmdata.max = end;
    // create thread
    res = pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, check_circuit_thread_function, (void*)&mmdata);
    if(res != 0){
      printf("Thread creation error %d\n", i);
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    printf("Thread %d, check_circuit:- min: %d, max %d\n ", i, start, end);
    // sleep for giving thread time to get its parameters
    // otherwise semaphores are needed
    sleep(1);
    start = end+1;
    end = end + each_thread_Z;
}
// join all threads to this main thread to get result from it
for(int i = 0; i < thread_count; i++){
    res = pthread_join(threads[i], &thread_result);
    if(res != 0){
      printf("Thread join error %d\n", i);
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}
gettimeofday(&t2, 0);
printf ("Execution time %fs\n", (t2.tv_sec-t1.tv_sec)+(t2.tv_usec-t1.tv_usec)*1e-6);
printf ("There are %d solutions\n", count);
return 0;
}
```

**Makefile***

```
threadcircuit: threadcircuit.c
    cc -o threadcircuit threadcircuit.c

clean:
    rm*.o
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the -pthread flag when compiling, like so `gcc -pthread -o threadcircuit threadcircuit .c`

Comment: Can you please tell me how the full make file will look, i having trouble making it. Thanks!

Comment: The structure of your make file looks okay, simply add a -pthread flag to the second line. In other words the 2nd line should look like what I've answered above.

Comment: Ohh i see... it worked, Thank You so much!